# By year and subgroup t.test

Tags: r

I want to perform t-test. Sorry, I'm awkward in English and R. Hope you understand my words.

my data are follow
Each year, the number of data 100.

```
year     group   x
2000     1      0.5
2000     0       2.3
2001    1       0.4
2001     0       0.3
2002     1       0.5
2002     0       2.3
2013     0       1.4
```

I want to run t.test by year and group.

```
t.test(x~group) #######by year
```

Comment: maybe something like this `aggregate(x ~ year + group, FUN=t.test, data=your.df`)?

Comment: I appreciate your interest. I want to run this. t.test(x~group, na.rm=T) every year, year-on-year, by year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling there's an easier way to do this, but here's one way...

```
# sample dataset - you already have this
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(year=rep(2000:2010,each=100),
                 group=rep(0:1,each=50),
                 x = rnorm(1100,1,.2))

# you start here
result <- sapply(unique(df$year),
                 function(yr)c(year=yr,t.test(x~group,df[df$year==yr,])))
result <- data.frame(t(result))
result[1:3,]
#   year   statistic parameter   p.value                conf.int             estimate null.value alternative                  method  data.name
# 1 2000 -0.09348405   95.7926 0.9257143 -0.07505382, 0.06830255   1.020090, 1.023465          0   two.sided Welch Two Sample t-test x by group
# 2 2001   -1.199856   96.7473 0.2331252 -0.12175014, 0.03000825 0.9695029, 1.0153739          0   two.sided Welch Two Sample t-test x by group
# 3 2002  -0.5876951  96.76143  0.558106 -0.10677870, 0.05799052 0.9937377, 1.0181318          0   two.sided Welch Two Sample t-test x by group
```

If you just want the p-values, for instance, do this:

```
result <- sapply(unique(df$year),
                 function(yr)c(year=yr,p.value=t.test(x~group,df[df$year==yr,])$p.value))
result <- data.frame(t(result))
head(result)
#   year   p.value
# 1 2000 0.9257143
# 2 2001 0.2331252
# 3 2002 0.5581060
# 4 2003 0.5621920
# 5 2004 0.4849300
# 6 2005 0.8650815
```

Comment: Thank you for sparing your precious time for me